# VB6 How to return a string value from form2 to form 1

Tags: vb6

in my project there are two forms:
first form i named it frmSettings , i will use text boxes to save values in INI file.
second form i named it frmSelectFolder ,  i had included with DirListBox and 2 Command buttons

[image]

as shown in attached image above in Settings form i have 8 text boxes and 8 command buttons to browse for folder path that it will be selected from frmSelectFolder

how to use frmSelectFolder for all text boxes without duplicating this form per each command button to return DirlistBox Control value ?

Comment: Every time the button is pressed in Settings, call a function that shows the SelectFolder form and returns the folder.  This returned folder is assigned to the TextBox.

Comment: You seem to be a beginner, so I have to ask why you're using VB6? It's ridiculously out of date at this point. You'd be much better off starting with either VB.Net or better yet C#.

Comment: Dear Brian . i can call the function that show SelectFolder form this is ok, what i mean here is just when i pressed button 1 it show the SelectFolder form then it return the string value to text1, it is same when i pressed button to it show the same form SelectForm and it returns the valve to text2 and so on .so you can help me on this ?

Comment: Dear Slugsie , I'M using VB6 because the Project we are used here have a tons of source codes , for this time we satisfied to use vb6

Comment: Dear Mohamed, if you have a ton of source code in VB6 there surely must be a similar interaction implemented in it -- a primary form calls into a secondary form and passes an input parameter and on success receives a result in output parameter. This is basic programming 101 in every programming language IMO. I can write you a small snippet as an answer if you need help how it can be done in 10-20 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code for secondary `frmSelectFolder` form

```
Option Explicit

Private m_bConfirm          As Boolean

Public Function Init(sPath As String) As Boolean
    Dir1.Path = sPath
    Show vbModal
    If m_bConfirm Then
        sPath = Dir1.Path
        '--- success
        Init = True
    End If
    Unload Me
End Function

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    If LenB(Dir1.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a path!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    m_bConfirm = True
    Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    If UnloadMode <> vbFormCode Then
        Cancel = 1
        Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is how to call `Init` method above from primary `frmSettings`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdStartupPath_Click()
    Dim sPath           As String
    Dim oFrmSelector    As New frmSelectFolder
    
    sPath = txtStartupPath.Text
    If oFrmSelector.Init(sPath) Then
        txtStartupPath.Text = sPath
        txtStartupPath.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDownloadPath_Click()
    Dim sPath           As String
    Dim oFrmSelector    As New frmSelectFolder
    
    sPath = txtDownloadPath.Text
    If oFrmSelector.Init(sPath) Then
        txtDownloadPath.Text = sPath
        txtDownloadPath.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a link to a complete sample project for you to research: [SelectFolder.zip](https://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/SelectFolder.zip)

Comment: Dear wqw , that's what i need exactly, i appreciate your kindness.